# How to draw bezier curve path based on path i have drawn and several points?

Tags: c#, path, bezier

Hi.I want to draw a red curve path based on existed blue curve path.[Refer this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYlfR.png) And I try to build the red path using Bezier in-code. Below is my code.

This is where I define and pass my Points.

```
  newFinal.Insert(0, nodeBegin); //add in starting node at beginning drawing purpose
        Point[] AToB = new[] { new Point(48, 242), new Point(-35, 250), new Point(48, 350) };
        Point[] AToE = new[] { new Point(48, 242), new Point(150, 240), new Point(135, 245) };
        Point[] BToG = new[] { new Point(48, 350), new Point(150, 240), new Point(135, 340) };
        Point[] BToA = new[] { new Point(48, 350), new Point(-35, 250), new Point(48, 242) }; 
        Point[] EToA = new[] { new Point(135, 245), new Point(150, 240), new Point(48, 242) };
        Point[] GToB = new[] { new Point(135, 340), new Point(105, 370), new Point(48, 350) };

  for (i = 0; i < newFinal.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            switch (newFinal[i])
            {
                case 'a':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'b')
                        drawBezier(AToB[0], AToB[1],AToB[2]);
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'e')
                        drawBezier(AToE[0], AToE[1], AToE[2]);
                    break;


                case 'b':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'a')
                        drawBezier(BToA[0], BToA[1], BToA[2]);
                    else if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'g')
                        drawBezier(BToG[0], BToG[1], BToG[2]);
                    break;

                case 'e':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'a')
                        drawBezier(EToA[0], EToA[1], EToA[2]);
                    break;

                case 'g':
                    if (newFinal[i + 1] == 'b')
                        drawBezier(GToB[0], GToB[1], GToB[2]);
                        break;
              }
          }
```

This is where i pass my Points:

```
private void drawBezier(Point point1, Point point2, Point point3) //This is the class to draw the blue curve path
    {

        BezierSegment bezier = new BezierSegment()
        {
            Point1 = point1,
            Point2 = point2,
            Point3 = point3,
            IsStroked = true
        };

        PathFigure figure = new PathFigure();
        figure.Segments.Add(bezier);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        path.Data = new PathGeometry(new PathFigure[] { figure });

        MyCanvas.Children.Add(path);


        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        PointAnimation pointAnim = new PointAnimation();
        pointAnim.From = bezier.Point1;
        pointAnim.To = bezier.Point3;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(pointAnim,path);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(pointAnim,new PropertyPath("Data.Figures[2].Segments[2].Point3"));
    }
```

However the the red path drawn in a weird curve. For example,when i want to draw a to b, [this happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKzWp.png) Another example, draw g to b, [this happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nofah.png) It's like the curve cannot draw from the 1st Point. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

A BezierSegment object is in fact a cubic Bezier curve, which requires 4 points to be fully-defined. The Point1, Point2 and Point3 properties of a BezierSegment is for the first control point, the 2nd control point and the end point. The start point of the cubic Bezier curve is the "current point" of the path object. So, you should set the StartPoint property for the PathFigure to wherever you want the cubic Bezier curve to start.